# Redirect Mobile User to Mobile Subdirectory While Maintaining Path Using Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, path

I have this code which works perfectly while maintaining path which I want:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com\$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mobilecookie=true

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

but I want the mobile user redirected to `example.com/m` which is the folder where the mobile site files are

Right now it's redirecting the mobile user to `m.example.com` while maintaining path, but I want the mobile user to go from `example.com` to `example.com/m` while maintaining path.

Can anyone tell me where to add the directory in that code?

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect to a subfolder, .htaccess file should be like;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Your line to replace "get" with "got". It will replace get.php with got.php.php. Following line must be either "RewriteRule ^get(.*) /got.php" or "RewriteRule ^get(.*) /got$1"
RewriteRule ^get(.*) /got.php$1

# You are redirecting example.com to www.example.com. But your mobile site URL is http://example.com/m. So, there must be a control which excludes mobile agents.
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11.222.33.44 [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

# Remove www for mobile agents.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Add /m to URI for mobile agents (if it hasn't added yet)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[/]?m [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/m/$1 [QSA,L]

BrowserMatchNoCase "Apache-HttpClient" bots

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bots

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: No that is not working. I already tried adding /m . when i add that it says the page contains too many server redirects and ads a lot of m's after the url like this example.com/m/m/m/m/m/m/m/m/m/file.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. This is now redirecting to the subfolder but now when i'm clicking a download link in that redirected page its opening like this http://www.example.com/mhttp://www.example.com/got.php.........so something is still wrong. :)

Comment: @AnkitTalwar Can you share the final version of your .htaccess file?

Comment: What does 3. line stand for? Do you simply want to redirect get.php to got.php? If so, this would be OK;
`RewriteRule ^get.php(.*)$ got.php$1`
If you want to add www to non-www URL's, 4. ve 5. line would be;
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: The got.php is for downloading of a file. The guy who made the script added it and he's an excellent coder so i know that code is right. The 4th and 5th line work fine with the current code as it is. The problem is with the code you gave me. Its redirecting perfectly to a subfolder while maintaining path but when it redirects and i click the download button on that page the link opens like this    http://www.example.com/mhttp://www.example.com/got.php...... hence the download fails! Its fine tho, i might have to hire a coder to get this fixed. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciated :)

Comment: What is the URL of that download buton?

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out. Replace line 16 with `RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}^(.*)$ /m/$1 [L]`

Comment: The URL of the download button is generated, so its always different. OK so now when it gets redirected the entire page is loading without CSS or JAVA files, hence the page looks broken, but the download button in it is working now!. So now the redirected URL looks like this www.example.com/code...but the mobile files are at example.com/m so how to fix the page looking broken problem plus its only getting redirected is a user is coming from example.com/code but if a user is coming from example.com/custom.php/code it does not get redirected. We're getting close. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: [This .htaccess file](http://pastebin.com/msVuyEGa) works as expected. I added some comments. You can edit depending on your specific needs.

Comment: This is not even close to working. It keeps redirecting. Your previous code was good but it wasn't picking up the css and java and the other thing i told you about. Anyways its alright, you have helped enough. Thanks :)

Comment: If there is no index.php in your web root, it is possible to experience a redirect loop. Otherwise, there is no unexpected redirection. Try with another browser or clear your browser cache.